# Cannot register two dynamic routes under the same URL

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

I am struggling establishing the following route structure:

**Routing.module.ts**

```
const forumRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'forum', component: ForumComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: ForumListComponent },
      { path: ':categoryId', component: ForumCategoryComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: ':threadId', component: ForumSingleComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

both paths work well but the problem is whenever I click on routerLink

```
<div [routerLink]="['../thread', threadId ]">
```

the paths get updated but the template always pertains to ForumCategoryComponent

> { path: ':categoryId', component: ForumCategoryComponent, pathMatch:
>   'full' },

I tried using pathMatch full but i does not yield any effect.

How can I register this? Is it even possible?

Comment: How would the router be able to differentiate between category and thread?

Answer (score 0):

pathMatch: 'full' is only for the route segment, the router can't resolve by parameter name in this way so he resolve the first route who match all segments.

Exemple, if you enter the url in your browser he obviously can't know which one you want to navigate,

So I recommend you to differentiate the path between your two last children (simpliest way to solve)